# Marklogic performance with JAVA API on Rawcombined Query

Tags: marklogic

I have installed Marklogic 8 on my 8GB RAM machine and have 10 Million documents inserted to it. I am using Java API to query the database and get first 1000 matched documents.My Query(Rawcombined Query) involves 2 PathRange indexed **JSON** attributes and one Word query. When i logged the time taken in my java program, search function takes 20seconds to get the 1000 documents.

Can anyone please let me know what could be the factors that drive these type of performance hit?

Comment: Thanks @grtjn for the suggestion.

Comment: Could you please share your query, code, and some representative sample documents?  It could make a big difference whether you are using the bulk API (DocumentManager.search) or search API (QueryManager.search).  Also whether you are using summaries, extracting from documents, or getting back entire documents.  Also, could you elaborate on why you want to get back 1000 documents instead of a normal page size (10-50)?

Comment: I am using search API .                                            qm.search(querydef, resultsHandle);
 MatchDocumentSummary[] docSummaries = resultsHandle.getMatchResults();
 System.out.println("Listing "+docSummaries.length+" documents:\n");

Comment: I tried pagination to get 50 documents, but even now the response time is 17seconds. I will restart marklogic server every time i take the stats for the run(to make sure the query is run for the first time in the system). Does the marklogic restart causing this big response time?

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet.  Now I know you're not using bulk.  And thanks for trying a page size of 50, now we know it's not likely the doc download slowing things down, unless your docs are huge.  Could you share your query, search options, and some representative sample documents? One of the first things to check is whether your query is running unfiltered.  With that response time, it may be doing filtering which can really slow things down.

Comment: sample structure of the doc {
 "id": 2,
 "a": "DDDDD",
 "b": "DEEEEE,
 "c": 20,
 "cu": 20.0,
 "cur": 40000.0,
 "cla": 3.0,
 "cou": "ZZZ",
 "s": "ZZZZZZ",
 "pe": "abcccccccccc",
 "fm": false,
 "ta": "",
 "de": "",
 "zi": "20850",
 "cr": 1370420104000,
 "mo": 1419988039000,
 "em": [],
 "ed": [],
 "ce": [],
 "cl": [],
 "aw": [],
 "so": [],
 "pr": [],
 "co": [],
 "c": "FFFFFFFFFFFFF",
 "r": [],
 "av": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
 "ra": [],
 "in": [],
 "em": "",
 "em": [],
 "sc": [{
  "id": 4,
  "ex": "AA AAA SSSS",
  "st": "QQQQQ"
 },
 {
  "id": 12,
  "ex": "AA AAA SSSS",
  "st": "CCCCCCCC"
 },
 .......
}

Comment: Above is only a structure of the document. My Query is like, Get all documents  with sc/ex="AA AAA SSSS" and sc/st="QQQQQ" and word query(say ZZZZZZZ)

Comment: Thanks for the pseudo-query.  However, we would need the specific code & options used to create the query before we can see whether your query is unfilterered or not.  For now, I'll provide an answer recommending you try to make sure your query runs unfiltered.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend getting smaller pages, and allow for pagination through results. Searching is fast, pulling up the actual documents relatively slow. Pull up around 10 to 50 docs per page max for good performance.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your query runs unfiltered, meaning all query clauses can be resolved against indexes.  That may require creating some range indexes.  Given the pseudo-query you provided, I see nothing that would require a filtering step.  If your query is running very slowly you either have a problem with the hardware sizing, OS config, or query.  The first thing to check on a slow-running query is to make sure it runs unfiltered.

See [Fast Pagination and Unfiltered Searches](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered) in the docs, and specific to the Java API, [Query Options](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/query-options#id_66439).

Comment: Thanks@ SamMefford.I tried the unfiltered search but the response time is not great. Response time is now 13 seconds.

Comment: Any way you could share your actual query, search options, and indexes?

Comment: I am constrained to share the original details as data has PII.

Comment: I understand.  Any way you could share a sanitized version where you change the field names & values to match the sample structured of the doc you shared?  The challenge is that the pseudo-query you shared isn't clear whether you're using range indexes or container queries or something else.  And without the search options and indexes there are a lot of unknowns.  Have you read through https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance ?